# Loading an .ico from web and convert to BitmapSource

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmapimage, ico

Im trying to load a file of type .ICO from web and use it as an image in my windows phone. But I get an error when trying to set the source of the BitmapImage. Here is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) => { 
    if (e.Cancelled) return; 
    if (null != e.Error) throw e.Error; 

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); 
    image.SetSource(e.Result); 
    this.Favicon = image; 
};

client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"http://mysite/myimage.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Does BitmapImage support "ico" files? how to convert an "ico" to a supported BitmapImage file.

THe solution must work on Windows Phone 7.

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only formats supported by `BitmapImage` seem to be PNG and JPG.

Not completely stated here, but implied by the comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(VS.95).aspx

A silverlight implementation of .ico handling is here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jstegman/archive/2009/09/13/silverlight-ico-icon-decoder-parser.aspx

You might have to modify it to be compatible with the version of silverlight on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Shame, its not supported really (http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/73618/449043.aspx#449043) and this implementation does not work perfectly... I using a service from www.getfavicon.org...