# Show .ico Files in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, icons, windows-phone, favicon

I'm building an app for Windows Phone 8 that will be able to show the favicon of a website, but the problem is that, when the image is an icon, I get an exception telling me that the image type isn't supported.
I've tried to convert the image to png in the WCF service that my app uses, but it seems that both Azure and my other hosting service don't support the `System.Drawing.Image` namespace.
Now I'm looking for a way to convert ico to png in the app, even if it means having a native lib, but I cannot find any lib that would do it.
Does anyone have a solution for this? I don't care if I have to do it in the app or in the service...

If I could make it work with Windows Phone 7 either would be better, but just Phone 8 would solve the issue...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807124/loading-an-ico-from-web-and-convert-to-bitmapsource) helps. If things still don't work you could consider one of the many online image convert web services.

Comment: The links in the post are unavailable, I've tried to download the source one of the links provided and I couldn't, I'm losing my hopes on this. Google S2 is horrible as it doesn't find a lot of favicons and geticon.org converts everything to 16x16 pngs, I wanted it in the original size.
I can't find any image convertion services that have some kind of api for me to call within my app.
It's really a horrible limitation in Windows Phone!